# Injected authentication in RestAssuredMockMvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, rest-assured

I am writing a unit test for my controller that has an injected Authentication parameter

```
 @RequestMapping(value = Mappings.PEOPLE, method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public ResponseEntity<?> people(HttpServletRequest request, Authentication authentication, @RequestBody Person person) {
     ...
 }
```

I don't know how to set the authenticaion inside of my test. Here is what I have so far.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class PeopleTest {

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup(new PeopleController());
    }

    @Test
    public void testKanbanOnlyScan() {
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("username", "password"));
        given()
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .body(new Person("Davey Jones"))
        .when()
            .post("/people")
        .then()
            .statusCode(is(HttpStatus.OK.value()));
    }
}
```

But authentication is null in my controller during the test. How can I inject authentication into a controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MockMVC for test your controller using something like:

```
@Autowired
MockMVC mockMvc;
mockMvc.perform("/your-controller-path").with(authentication(authentication))
```

For more details take a look in spring docs

[preview-spring-security-test-web-security](https://spring.io/blog/2014/05/23/preview-spring-security-test-web-security)

Answer (score 0):

You can still use RestAssuredMockMvc, if you are using the WebApplicationContext.

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class TodoControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @BeforeEach
    void init() {
        RestAssuredMockMvc.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext);
    }

    @Test
    void secured_api_should_react_with_default(){
        given()
        .when()
            .get("/todo/")
        .then()
            .statusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
    }

    @Test
    public void secured_api_should_give_http_200_when_authorized() {
        given()
            .auth().with(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.httpBasic("foo", "bar"))
        .when()
            .get("/todo/")
        .then()
            .statusCode(HttpStatus.OK.value());

    }
}
```